# Use iOS8 custom keyboard with Image

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, custom-keyboard

I am iOS application developer.
I am working in iOS custom keyboard extension.
I need to show some image in my custom keyboard, that I have already done.
But tapping on that image the same image will be paste/send into the text area (`UITextField` or `UITextView`).

I have done the below code for this:

```
 NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
        textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gun.png"];      

 CGFloat scaleFactor = 10;
 textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:textAttachment.image.CGImage scale:scaleFactor orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
 NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
 //[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(6, 1) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];

 [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", attrStringWithImage]];
```

But the image is not showing in the text area.

Comment: Directly image not send in textDocumentProxy

Comment: You use pasteboard in your project